# What certificate to use along with neo4j@code-signer

Tags: ssl, neo4j, npx, neo4j-desktop

I'm currently developing a graph app for neo4j desktop. From what i figured out, app should be signed with [neo4j@code-signer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@neo4j/code-signer) (which utilizes node-forge i presume).
It needs a certificate and private key (and password probably).

What i can't figure out is, what kind of certificate is actually needed?

1. I signed my app with self-signed certificate which produced a big untrusted warning in neo4j desktop (touche, i should have known).
2. I used my ssl key which enabled my HTTPS, but this produced an error in neo4j desktop:

> Certificate keyUsage or basicConstraints conflict or indicate that
> the certificate is not a CA. If the certificate is the only one in the
> chain or isn't the first then the certificate must be a valid CA.

Both options **did** produce **signature.pem** file.

Do i need to buy a **Code Signing Certificate** for this? If so, standard or EV?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is going to help somebody:
There wasn't any issue with my certificates.

I got an answer from neo4j offical, that they are (at the time being) signing apps internaly, and that there is no automated way to do this (yet).